# Installing librdkafka on Windows for PHP XAMPP

Tags: php, apache-kafka, queue

Please help me to install librdkafka on windows xampp for php development.

PHP : 7.1.12, x86, Thread Safe, MSVC14

I downloaded compatible package from https://pecl.php.net/package/rdkafka/3.0.5/windows

Copied `php_rdkafka.dll` to `ext` folder of my php xampp and `librdkafka.dll` to `System32` folder (also to `ext` folder).

But the extension is not working. I am getting following error:

> PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_rdkafka.dll' - The specified module could not be
>   found. in Unknown on line 0

I suspect that `librdkafka` is not properly installed.

Comment: I upvoted, but maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47589688/the-program-cant-start-because-php7-dll-is-missing-from-your-computer/47831555#47831555

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to make it work by doing below steps.

1. Copy `librdkafka.dll` to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` if x86 otherwise copy to `C:\Windows\System32`. Don't copy to both folders.
2. Then run `regsvr32 librdkafka.dll` in command prompt.
3. Then copy `php_rdkafka.dll` to `ext` folder of your php.
4. Then add `extension=php_rdkafka.dll` to your `php.ini` file
5. Restart PHP, DONE!!!

Comment: I have done the same but getting this warning (PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_rdkfaka.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_rdkfaka.dll (The specified module could not be found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_C:\xampp\php\ext\php_rdkfaka.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0)

also when I have run the PHP file getting this error Uncaught Error: Class 'RdKafka\Producer' not found in

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer did not work for me, instead I installed the dependency as following:

- Download the library from https://pecl.php.net/package/rdkafka
- Extract the file `librdkafka.dll` to the the root PHP directory (same level as `php.exe` for example `C:\xampp\php`).
- Extract the file `php_rdkfaka.dll` to the `ext` folder: `C:\xampp\php\ext`
- Add the line `extension=php_rdkafka.dll` to the `php.ini`.
- Restart the server.

---

**Note:** within the library you will download, you will find a `README.md` with a link to the official documentation.

Comment: I don't know if the first answer would have worked for me, but this certainly felt less intrusive to my system, and it worked great. Thank you!